# How do you name parameters when using the argument unpacking operator, python

Tags: python

In a function you can specify the names of the params so the order doesn't matter ie:

```
func(a = 1, c = 3, b = 2)

def func(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c
```

Now say we want to specify the params using an argument unpacking operator, ie:

```
params = [a = 1, c = 3, b = 2] 

func(*params)
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: Dictionaries.....

Comment: `params = {'a':1, 'c':3, 'b': 2}` then `func(**params)`

Comment: wow awesome! thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary:
You can use the `dict` `__init__` function to get convenient syntax:

```
params=dict(a=1, c=3, b=2)
```

Then unpack the params:

```
func(**params)
```